# How PDO transaction api works?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

Here is my code structure:

```
// db connection here

try {
    $dbh_conn->beginTransaction();

    $stm = $dbh_conn->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM resend_pass WHERE token = ?");
    $stm->execute(array('value'));
    $num_rows = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($num_rows) {
        echo 'one'; die;

    } else {
        echo 'two'; die;

    }

    $dbh_conn->commit();

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    $dbh_conn->rollBack();

    echo 'three'; die;

}
```

When exactly that query executes? You know, my script works exactly as expected. But I'm wonder how? As you see there is an `if - else` statement before `commite()`; Also both `if` and `else` have `die;` in their blocks. So as far as I know, this line never executes:

```
$dbh_conn->commit();
```

Because there is surly a `die` before it. But surprisingly my code works as well. Here is all possible outputs:

- It prints `one` if `value` exists as a token in the `resend_pass` table.
- It prints `two` if `value` doesn't exist as a token in the `resend_pass` table.
- It prints `three` if there is an error *(like syntax SQL error)*

See? All fine. But how? When exactly `commit()` function executes? Before those `die`s ?

**Note:** The engine of `resend_pass` is *innoDB*.

Comment: when php exits, it cleans up, which means it disconnects from the database. mysql will see that and issue a rollback to clear up any "garbage" the connection littered around. `die` kills the script immediately. unless you registered a shutdown function, your commit call would never even get a chance to execute.

Comment: @MarcB *"your commit call would never even get a chance to execute"* -- Wrong .. As I said, that query executes and `if($num_rows) {` performs based on the result of that query.

Comment: what does it matter? php doesn't time travel. just because there's a "die" command somewhere in the "future" of  a script doesn't mean php will refuse to run the script at all. It runs the code line-by-line, doing exactly what the code says. it runs your query. it fetches a result. it tests that results, THEN it might `die`.

Comment: @MarcB All I'm trying to understand, Is my script's structure fine? Or should I change the structure of it?

Comment: and this is a bad query to test with. the select doesn't CHANGE the db at all. try doing an insert. insert a value, then die before and after a committ call and see what happens in the db.

Comment: @MarcB Good idea .. `INSERT` statement would be better.

Comment: as is, it's ok, though you may NOT want to depend on php/mysql doing a rollback in cleanup situations. maybe for some reason oracle will reverse the logic in some future mysql version and commit outstanding transactions at shutdown. can't see why, it'd be extraordinarily stupid, but logic has never been something use in the same sentence as oracle anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries execute when `execute()` is called (note that `query()` calls `execute()`).

If the query changes data in a table that supports transactions, the change is rolled back if the PDO object is freed, either because the object goes out of scope or the script terminates and cleans up. This is due to the PDO code, not MySQL.

If the query changes data in a table that does not support transactions (e.g. a MyISAM table), the change is permanent at the time it is executed, and it cannot be rolled back.

There are some [SQL statements that perform an implicit commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html). They would be made permanent as soon as they executed, even if your script dies before calling `commit()`.

As @MarcB mentioned, your example shows a read-only `SELECT` statement. It would be easier to test the behavior if you use an `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE`.

Comment: So my current structure is fine?

Comment: Yes, it's fine. If your script calls `die()` the transaction will be rolled back.

Comment: I've a pretty similar question. Please if you have some free time take a look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579529/how-my-script-rollbacks-the-queries-before-executing-rollback-function