# How PDO rollbacks the queries before executing rollBack() function?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here is my script:

```
try {
    $dbh_con->beginTransaction();

        $stmt1 = $dbh_conn->prepare("UPDATE activate_account_num SET num = num + 1");
        $stmt1->execute();

        $stmt2 = $dbh_con->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM activate_account WHERE token = ?");
        $stmt2->execute(array($token));
        $num_rows = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ( $num_rows['user_id'] ){
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'all fine';

        } else {
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'token is invalid';
            header('Location: /b.php');
             exit();
        }

    $dbh_con->commit();

    header('Location: /b.php');
    exit();

} catch(PDOException $e) {

    $dbh_con->rollBack();

    $_SESSION['error'] = 'something is wrong';
    header('Location: /b.php');
    exit();
}
```

As you see, that `else` block contains `exit()` function. So when that `else` block executes, then surely that `rollBack();` function doesn't execute, because before executing `rollBack();`, the script exits. But surprisingly that `UPDATE` statement rollbacks.. How ?

Answer (score 3):

Transactions are used when it's critical that all changes happen together, or no change happens at all.

To preserve the integrity of the DB in the event of an abrupt stoppage (eg: script exits unexpectedly, server crashes, power supply is cut...), implementations of transactions will keep you protected by not making any change until `commit()` is called.  When you `execute` intermediary queries, the change is not actually hitting the database, but held in limbo.  If you exit without committing, the limbo is just thrown away.

When you `rollBack()`, the limbo is also just thrown away.

Comment: Great explanations .. +1

Comment: Yes, this explanation is correct in concept. But for what it's worth, what InnoDB really does internally is copy the original data to the "rollback segment", apply the update to the data in place (anticipating you will commit most changes). If you do rollback, InnoDB works in the background to restore the copy preserved in the rollback segment back to the original place in the table.

Comment: The reason is that the "limbo" concept you describe would need to be enormous to hold changes, since there's no limit to the amount of work that could be in a transaction. It has to be saved durably. And that means that your eventual COMMIT is pretty quick, since the data has already been saved. It just has to update the state of the transaction. The obsolete data in the rollback segment is gradually garbage-collected.

Comment: @BillKarwin I simplified to make the answer useful from the DB consumer's perspective.  Your ansswer brings up a question though: in case of sudden power loss, would the uncommitted changes persist in the DB? I maybe misunderstand but if the update is actually applied to the data, wouldn't it mean that another script querying the DB would see the uncommitted changes?

Comment: Yes, uncommitted data is persisted in the database, and survives a power loss. Once mysqld comes back up, it will get to work cleaning up the mess.

Comment: Another script can't see uncommitted changes it shouldn't see. Modified pages are annotated with the transaction that applied the change. My transaction inspects the transaction id on the page, knows that it shouldn't view that version of that data, and instead follows a pointer on that page to the prior version of the data, stored in the rollback segment.

Answer (score 1):

In the normal case, php client disconnect when scripts exits and that will cause a rollback in MySQL.